# Accessing vagrant on port 80 locally on mac

Tags: macos, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm trying run vagrant on port 80 locally. In the Vagrant file I have tried the following two things, which does not work. When I go to localhost or 127.0.0.1 in the browser the page will load for a while and then eventually redirect to port 8080 with a "This webpage is not available" error...

```
config.trigger.after [:provision, :up, :reload] do
    system('echo "
        rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
        rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8443
        " | sudo pfctl -ef - >/dev/null 2>&1;'
    )
end
```

---

```
config.trigger.after [:provision, :up, :reload] do
    system('echo "
        rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to 127.0.0.1 port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
        " | sudo pfctl -ef - > /dev/null 2>&1;')  
end
```

(I did install the vagrant-triggers plugin. I'm on a Mac 10.10.5)

What seems to be missing?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using vagrants own forward_port configuration: `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 80`? Mac OSX doesn't let any non-root user bind to a port < 1024, so you may be better off leaving vagrant binding to 8080 with no forward port, and using ipfw to forward 80 -> 8080.

Comment: I'm am using Vagrants forwarded_port `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080`. `ipfw` is removed from osx in Yosemite and I am trying to use `pfctl` but can't get it to work...